# What task can a sigle layer perceptron do better than a multilayer perceptron?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, perceptron

Are there tasks a sigle layer perceptron can do better than a multilayer perceptron?
If yes, do you have an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any dataset, where the underlying relation is linear, but number of training datapoints is very low will benefit from having the linear model to begin with. It is a relation of task + amount of data, more than nature of the task itself. Another example could be a bit contrived task of extrapolation, where you train on data in [0, 1] x [0, 1] but for some reason test for values in >1,000,000. If the underlying relation was linear, a linear model should have much lower error in the extreme extrapolation regime, as a nonlinear one can just do whatever it "wants" and bend anywhere outside [0,1] x [0,1].